# How to add [ngStyle] directive dynamically in ionic 3 / angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-directive

This is what I had and it was working, it was bounded to `progress` method and it was displaying correctly:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'width.%': progress()}"></div>
```

Now I have to create the element dynamically:

```
let myDiv = <HTMLElement>(document.createElement('div'));
```

but I can't seem to find a way to bind the progress method to my dynamically created element.

Code using [renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer) as suggested by @fatemefazli which doesn't have change detection so it doesn't render when data becomes available nor listens to change of progress method: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpyfmn

The decision to create DOM elements dynamically comes from the need to attach pan gesture using [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/) which requires to attach a listener like so:

```
addGestures(elem){
    var hammer = new Gesture(elem);
    hammer.listen();

    hammer.on('pan', (e) => this.Pan(e));
  }
```

I tried to create an event publish / emitter but I don't have a trigger to publish it.

Comment: Not the direct answer, but can't you achieve the same thing by using `*ngIf` instead of dynamically creating an element?

Comment: I had it implemented through template like you say but new requirements / implementation requires creating the element dynamically, I know this sounds a little bit overcomplicated because of lack of information about the big picture but it is the only option which I have now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: angular has build-(ish) in gesture support from hammerjs: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support and even if it didn't, there is no need to create an element dynamically. You can just get the element reference from the template, and add a gesture to it in the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TricheTriche said, you shouldn't directly access the DOM. In fact, not only it's not recommended but will not work for dynamic changes, since it's not really running inside the angular zone anymore.

What you need to do is:

1. create a new placeholder in your current component that will host (2)
2. create a new directive that is in charge of listening and handling events , and also rendering any style changes
3. use [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) to dynamically inject (2) into (1)

Check more details on Angular's page [Angular's Dynamic Component Load page](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), in which they present a running [example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-component-loader/stackblitz.html) of something similar to what you need

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer){
    this.myDiv = <HTMLElement>(document.createElement('div'));
    renderer.setElementStyle(this.myDiv , 'width', this.progress()+'%');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, tried it but it throws an error about the data which is used in progress method is undefined when rendering the template.

Initially it was displaying Can not find "renderer" and I used it as this.render.setElementStyle....

Comment: After going around and adding it only after the data is available, I get: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.style')

Comment: @August may you please post your complete code or progress ? 
i tried this code was working in a simple condition, maybe yours is different.

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think the problem arises from the difference between "style" directive (used in this answer) which is a HTML directive bound to a value and NgStyle (used in my previous implementation) which is an Angular directive which "listens" for availability of the data over time.

Comment: Implemented but it doesn't do same thing as NgStyle: doesn't get rendered when the values becomes available and the value doesn't get constantly updated like it was doing when used with NgStyle. See my previous comment.

Comment: @August maybe you're right i made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzzmgk) check it in console and make your changes would be good for me to understand,

Comment: @fatemefazli Thank you for trying to help, here is a better case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpyfmn?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @August yes now i get, you are right, i couldn't find a way to change style dynamically, a way is to setElementStyle in progress function when you want to update it. thanks for your good question.

Comment: @fatemefazli I thank you for trying to help, your solution is a valid point but not for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to handle DOM change yourself (and adding an element is).

Even when using the renderer, this is something you want to avoid.

What I would suggest is to use event and data binding on a hard-coded element, like you did the first time.

And if you really need to create a div for any reasons, then please explain to us what you would like to achieve, because there's probably a solution for you that doesn't involve touching the DOM yourself.